# Is there a standardized Message format?

Tags: format, messaging, instant-messaging, standardized

There are several different messaging apps and services available such as: Slack, HipChat, IRC, Zoom Chat, etc...

Is there a standardized (or common) message format being used (or available) to represent these messages to ease developer integrations, similar to ISO8601 for date time format?

Comment: https://xmpp.org/

Comment: Thanks, do you know if services like Slack use xmpp?

Comment: Generally not..

Comment: Then why have a standard? LOL

Answer (score 1):

[XMPP](https://xmpp.org) is the closest we have to what you're asking for, there's a list of the servers that [support it in their website](https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html).

Unfortunately, the new generation of chat services (Slack, MS Teams, Mattermost, Discord, etc...) decided against using XMPP in favor of their own protocol. It gave them the flexibility to optimize for their platform's needs but made it almost impossible to interoperate with other clients, or to even migrate your messages from one service to another.